# How can I make modern search bar in PySide2?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I was making my own web browser until I realized that making a searchbar was a difficult task. I tried removing the title bar, but it didn't work out as expected because of `pyside2` limitations. Then, I made my own searchbar but it wasn't interactive and the design was awful. So, I was looking around to see how I can make a draggable searchbar without a titlebar with stylesheets included and I found no recourses online. Therefore, StackOverflow was my last thought on how I can resolve and ask for information about this issue. Please leave any comments if I made any mistakes, Thank you! :D

[image: microsoft-edge-inspiration]

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngine import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class BrowserEngine(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrowserEngine, self).__init__()
        self.webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.webview.load("https://www.duckduckgo.com")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
        
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.webview)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

class BrowserWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("DuckDuckGo")
        self.widget = BrowserEngine()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    module = BrowserWindow().show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't how the search bar would be related to the title bar. Besides, your question is actually extremely broad. What do you mean to implement in your "modern search bar"? Do you mean an address bar with search features? Support for fix-up of partially invalid addresses? Icon support? Auto-completion of previously typed URLs? Search engine suggestions? Drag&drop? Security warning indicators? Also, functionality is formally not related to design (it may work well and look ugly, or vice versa). Your question is too vague, and your code also shows *no* attempt in creating a "search bar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QlineEdit` and `setPlaceHolderText`, if you want some effects to use like google search completer, use `QCompleter`. Hope it helps you. As far as I come across, there is nothing called as search bar option in pyqt5.